# What is causing undefined control sequence?

Tags: errors, document-classes

I'm getting this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.64 ...p(- \frac{E_j - E_i}{k_B T}) & \quad \text
                                                  {:  E_j > E_i}\\
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.65     1 & \quad \text
                        {:  E_j<E_i}\\
?
```

which is from this:

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:hop}
w_{i,j}=w_0 exp(-2 \gamma R_{i,j})\left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    exp(- \frac{E_j - E_i}{k_B T}) & \quad \text{:  E_j > E_i}\\
    1 & \quad \text{:  E_j<E_i}\\
  \end{array} \right.
\end{equation}
```

But I don't understand why I get the error. This is my header:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{iopart}
%\newcommand{\gguide}{{\it Preparing graphics for IOP journals}}
%Uncomment next line if AMS fonts required
\usepackage{iopams}
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg,.gif}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset\centering
%\def\@cite#1{\textsuperscript{[#1]}}
\makeatother
```

And my class file is the standard IoP one from [here](http://authors.iop.org/atom/help.nsf/0/B042B0AF79C815B88025702000409514?OpenDocument)

Can anyone help me get read of this error?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The mistake is, as TeX also informs. It cannot find your `\text` command. The error lies probably in package `iopams` and should be noticed there. It seems that it does not load the ams math package (only its fonts) and thus you need to explicitly include that package as well.

On a side note you should also include `$` in your `\text` command.

Solution:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

Comment: *On a side note you should also include $ in your \text command.* Where in the text command? It renders $E_j$ etc fine.

Comment: Probably not in `\text{: E_j > E_i}` the `_` is a mathchar as well as `>`. You need `\text{: $E_j > E_i$}` unless `iopams` does magic for you! :)

Comment: I do in fact elieve some form of magic for me. Or, that due to `\text` not being recognised, it's ignored so `E_j` renders correctly.

Comment: So is your original problem solved? Then its fine. I havn't tried the `iopart` class so can not say if it changes the definition of `_`. It just seems against normal `TeX` packages to do this (unless it is grouped in the math environments). Glad it works! :)

Comment: I've just edited the `iopams` file to include the maths library. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 32):

The macro `\text` is undefined. You need to load the `amsmath` package or at least `amstext`.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

`\text` is defined in `amstext`, which is loaded by `amsmath`. Load the latter, because it offers many math functionality, such as aligned multi-line formulas and much more.

Comment: Now it is just returning lots of errors about extra `{` or missing `$` and it never finishes compiling.

Comment: @Pureferret Use text within `\text{...}` That's what it's for: escaping math mode. If you need math symbols within again, write `\text{word $\symbol$}` or even better, end the macro argument, such as `\text{word } \symbol \text{ and more text}`.

Comment: I just removed the `\text{...}` macro, and it runs smoothly now. I'll sacrifice that `:` for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Note to readers: `amsmath` is not compatible with `iopart`.

Answer (score 5):

A similar mistake might also be caused by something as simple as trying to build the wrong file(e.g. clicking a PDFLaTeX command while being in the "abstract" file, which is part of your document). You should be in your main file(where you call and "gather" all the "smaller" files) when you're building.

I hope this saves some time for newbies like me, as this page was the first suggestion when looking for this error.