# Why am I receiving an undefined control sequence for my equation?

Tags: math-mode, equations, sharelatex

I have an equation defined as

```
$$m^*(E) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} l(I_k) < m^*(E) + \varepsilon \text{ and } E \subseteq \cup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_k.$$
```

but I am receiving an uncontrolled sequence error. Is there a special package I need to use `\text{ and }`? If me equation is

```
$$m^*(E) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} l(I_k) < m^*(E) + \varepsilon E \subseteq \cup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_k.$$
```

I do not receive an error.

Comment: You need `amsmath` to use `\text{and}`

Comment: [ShareLaTeX](http://www.sharelatex.com) does not run Plain TeX, so this is definitely a LaTeX-related question. As such, it's a duplicate of [What is causing undefined control sequence?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41035/5764).